# I clicked a button but nothing happened, can you help me? using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

this is the question Shows the log-in form; the app must generate a message box notifying the user “Please Complete the required field” when the user leave the two text boxes blank ,while clicking the login button; wherein a generated message box pop and notify the user that “Wrong password!” when the user input the correct username and wrong password it will automatically clear the password textbox; wherein the app must generate a message box that notify the user that “Wrong Username!” if the user input the wrong username and correct password it will and automatically clear the username textbox; wherein the app must generate a messages box that notify the user that “Wrong Username and password!” if the user input both wrong username and wrong password it will automatically clear the password and username textboxes and set the text focus to the username textbox; wherein ;the app must notify the user “WELCOME” if when the user input the correct username and password it will automatically close the login activity and open the next activity.
Note: the Username and password must be both “admin”.

```
Button login;
EditText user, pass;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1 );
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2 );
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1 );
    login.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);   

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(user.equals("admin") && (pass.equals("admin"))){
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
        }else if (user.equals(null) && (pass.equals("admin"))) {
            System.out.println ("Please Complete Required Field!");
        }else if (user.equals("admin") && (pass.equals(null))) {
            System.out.println ("Please Complete Required Field!");     
        }else {
    System.out.println ("Wrong Username! or Wrong Password!");   
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Comment: Not yet, i cant solve my whole problem i dont know how to code in eclipse, can you solve it for me?

Comment: Note: as of 2016 eclipse is no longer supported for Android development. It is strongly encouraged to migrate your code to Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

**To detect whether the editText is empty or not:**

Change `(user.equals(null))` to `user.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0`

and `pass.equals(null)` to `pass.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0`

In your button implementation, write like `login.setOnClickListener(this)`; and **make sure your Activity/Fragment implement `OnClickListener`** like @pcg26 said.

Comment: HEY @john Joe 
can you do the problem for me, im basically new in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Is the activity implementing onclicklistener?

Simple a comment..  You can use `Log.e("MyActivity"," the error");` instead  `System.out.println ^^`

Comment: can i still use system.out.println?

Comment: is better LogCat! logcat is loong xD
The logcat is good to debug your code

Comment: login.setOnClickListener(this);   
and if you write a log in onClick it appears?

Comment: can you show me your code? can you please do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented onClickListener.
In your onClick method, You must use a **switch** or **if** statement to make sure that the button is clicked.
Something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.yourButtonID){
        // do here
    }
}
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.yourButtonID){
        // do here
    }
where should i input my if else statement? where should i put if my textbox is null or what?

Comment: You put if-else statement in "do here" to check your textbox. (just surround your code with my if statement above), like this: http://ideone.com/7M13Tk
Then use @John Joe solutions to check textbox. More over, You should not use System.out in android programming. Please use Log.e instead. About type of Log, you can see here: https://davidng94.wordpress.com/2016/01/27/android-log-v-log-d-log-i-log-w-log-e-when-to-use-each-one/